# How to convert array values to class objects in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a string value with comma separator,

```
string currency = "EUR:100;INR:500;CZK:500";
var _currency= currency.split(':');
```

now i get value in array like 
EUR:100
INR:500
CZK:500   in _currency variable.

now how to push this array values to my class

```
class CurrencyValue 
{
public string Currency {get;set;}
public int Amount{get;set;}
}
```

that is EUR to Currency  and 100 to Amount?

Comment: Loop throught the array, create the class instance and add to a list, array or whatever you want.

Comment: What you tried so far? if you did not try anything yet then this is good example to learn Linq `Select()`

Answer (score 0):

1. First split your string with semicolon, convert to string array.
2. Project your array into List as required.

```
string currency = "EUR:100;INR:500;CZK:500";
string[] strarray= currency.split(';');

List<CurrencyValue> lst= strarray.Select(s=>new CurrencyValue(s.Split(:)[0],s.Split(:)[1]));

foreach(CurrencyValue c in lst)
{
   //Loop through the list
}
```

```
class CurrencyValue 
{
  public string Currency {get;set;}
  public int Amount{get;set;}

  CurrencyValue(string Curr,int Amt)
  {
    Currency=Curr;
    Amount=Amt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<CurrencyValue> cvs = 
            currency.Split(';')
            .Select(z => z.Split(':'))
            .Select(z => new CurrencyValue(){Currency = z[0], Amount = int.Parse(z[1])});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `LINQ`

```
string currency = "EUR:100;INR:500;CZK:500";
var lst = currency.Split(';')
                  .Select(s => s.Split(':'))
                  .Select(x => new CurrencyValue { Currency = x[0], Amount = Convert.ToInt32(x[1].ToString()) })
                  .ToList();
```